# ggvis plot interferes with initial rendering of an R shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I have an app like the one below, where I'm trying to render some html based on inputs and also display a ggvis plot. The plot seems to interfere with the `htmlOutput()` because it does not appear when the app is first loaded. When the input changes, it finally renders as expected.

Also, if we start the app on a tab without a ggvis plot, the html renders as expected from the start.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("slider", label = "slider", min = 1, max = 5, value = 3),
  htmlOutput("text"),
  tabsetPanel(
    # selected = "tab b", # if I uncomment this line, the htmlOutput works as expected
    tabPanel(title = "tab a", ggvisOutput("plot")),
    tabPanel(title = "tab b", "Static text")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- reactive({
    mtcars %>% ggvis(~mpg, ~hp) %>% layer_points() %>% bind_shiny("plot")
  })
  output$text = renderUI({
    paste0("The slider value is ", input$slider)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

So, in this app, why doesn't the `htmlOutput()` appear when the app is loaded? How can I get it to appear when the app starts? Also, is this a bug of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is, that you are assigning the plot as a reactive to the output via `output$plot <- reactive(...)`.

Only `bind_shiny` should be used to connect a ggvis graphic to a shiny app:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)
library(datasets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("slider", label = "slider", min = 1L, max = nrow(mtcars), value = nrow(mtcars), step = 1L),
  htmlOutput("text"),
  tabsetPanel(
    # selected = "tab b", # if I uncomment this line, the htmlOutput works as expected
    tabPanel(title = "tab a", ggvisOutput("plot")),
    tabPanel(title = "tab b", "Static text")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    mtcars[1L:input$slider,] %>% ggvis(~mpg, ~hp) %>% layer_points() %>% bind_shiny("plot")
  })
    
  output$text = renderUI({
    paste0("The slider value is ", input$slider)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```